# What is an Angular State?

Tags: angularjs

I am from Asp.Net world, trying to understand what an Angular State mean.

What is an Angular State? Is it similar to an ascx component in Asp.Net?  Is it a sub page? Is it similar to a workflow state?

I heard many people talking about it, and I have been trying to search for articles which explains what a state is or does, but cannot find a good one for the beginner.

Do any of you know any good article? could you please help me to grab/understand the concept of angular state? thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: It might help you!!! 1. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views  2. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference is not to Angular itself but to an Angular Module called [Angular UI.Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router).  This module allows you to turn your Angular application into a [State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), and handle what appears on the view based on these states, rather than only on the URL parameters.  Many people consider this an essential Angular Module, and far more functional than the default `$routeProvider`.

The best reference for all the `$stateProvider` 
features is the [github repository wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation for the AngularJS UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki),

> - A state corresponds to a "place" in the application in terms of the overall UI and navigation.
> - A state describes (via the controller / template / view properties) what the UI looks like and does at that place.
> - States often have things in common, and the primary way of factoring out these commonalities in this model is via the state hierarchy, i.e.
>     parent/child states aka nested states.

Comment: When you copy text from some other source, even documentation, **you must link to the original source and use quote-formatting for the copied text**, otherwise you are plagiarizing.